# How do I store and retrieve user chats in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am writing an app which will have a chat function. I am using react native and firebase. My question is - how do I store a particular user chats in firebase and how do I later retrieve them? The current solution which I have is having two screens - `Chat.js` and `ListChats.js`. `Chat.js` is the screen which loads when I want to send message to another user. Once a user starts new chat with another user I am calling `createChat`:

```
const createChat = async () => {
  await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("chats")
    .add({
      //this is the part which bothers me the most
      users: [currentUser.uid, user.uid],
      lastMessage: "Send the first message",
      lastMessageTimestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
};
```

I am storing the two user ids in the `users` field. Later when a user press the `Send` button:

```
const onSend = () => {
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("chats")
    .doc(chat.id)
    .collection("messages")
    .add({
      creator: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
      text: textToSend,
      creation: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
};
```

So far so good. However, I have performance concerns when I go to the `ListChats.js` page. On this page I want to list all chats, which the current user has. So I am doing a call to firebase to fetch these chats in the following way:

```
function fetchUserChats() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("chats")
      .where("users", "array-contains", currentUser.uid)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        let chats = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          //do something
        });
      });
  };
}
```

My problem is that I am going through all the chats, then checking the `users` field, which is array containing two values (user ids) and then searching for my current user id. Is there a smarter/better way of fetching a particular user chats in terms of performance?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: This approach looks fine to me. What is the problem with your current solution? What doesn't work about it? Is there an error message or performance problem? If so, can you show the message you get, or show us how you measured the performance and what results you got?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen there is no problem. As I said in the question, I am concerned about the performance. It doesnt seem right to me, that in order to fetch particular user chats, I should go through all the cats in the db, then check if my current user id is included in the users field.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the problem, but as far as I can tell you are *not* going through all the chats. You're very specifically querying for `.where("users", "array-contains", currentUser.uid)`, which Firestore handles quite efficiently (it wouldn't support it if it couldn't).